# How to fix java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ".52"

Tags: android, numbers

> Hi, I am getting userInput from three editTexts and setting it to a TextView after multiplying.

> This is the code :

```
  float l = Float.parseFloat(etLength.getText().toString());
  float b = Float.parseFloat(etBreadth.getText().toString());
  float d = Float.parseFloat(etDepth.getText().toString());
  pitSize.setText(String.valueOf(l * b * d));
```

> If I type `0.52`, then the code works, but if I type `.52` the App crashes with this exception :

```
 java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ".52"
```

> Please let me know how to fix this Issue. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, just don't allow such string, this is not a number in fact... for human it is readable and "understandable", for electronic device floating point is BETWEEN numbers, not at the beginning or end

just detect if first/last character is a dot `.` and add then `0` before/after

```
String etString = etLength.getText().toString();
if (etString.startsWith(".")) {
    etString = "0" + etString
}
if (etString.endsWith(".")) {
    etString = etString + "0";
}
float l = Float.parseFloat(etString);
```

shorter version due to comments :)

```
etString = "0" + etLength.getText().toString();
if (etString.contains(".")) etString +=0;
```

assuming your `EditText` have proper filter (`android:inputType`)and won't allow multiple decimal separators `.` and `,`

note that in some languages it's a dot, in other is a coma, you may check what is set on running OS with

```
char separator = DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance().getDecimalSeparator();
```

but still you can't be shure that used keyboard respects that (oftnly keyboards always enter `.`), so check for both characters

Comment: Really needed an example here Sir, pls

Comment: thanks, but getting this error : Illegal escape character in string literal at the if condition line

Comment: @ashish check out edit and sample

Comment: Ok, trying now, pls wait a bit

Comment: You could just ALWAYS prepend a "0" to the string to deal with these kinds of problems. You don't have to check if the string begins with a decimal point first.

Comment: Good point! ;) just put always zero at beginning and `if (string.contains("."))` also on the end